# changing body in R shiny when I change menu item

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make the body change as I select different player names.

Here I defined my lists and matrix

```
nametext <- list(c(“roger” , “rafa” , “marat”))
bodytext <- list(c(“roger text”, “rafa text”, “marat text”))
titletext <- list(c(“The GOAT” , “The Toro”, “My Idol”))
alldata <- data.frame( nametext , bodytext, titletext)
```

In the next step I set up the dashboard page, including the sidebar menu

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = “Best Players in Tennis History”,
titleWidth = 300 #because the title is too long i had to increase the width of the header
),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 300, #to match the width of the header with the sidebar
sidebarMenu(id = “player”,
menuItem(“Roger Federer”, tabName = 1, icon = icon(“user”)),
menuItem(“Rafael Nadal”, tabName = 2, icon = icon(“flash”)),
menuItem(“Marat Safin”, tabName = 3, icon = icon(“fire”))
)
),
```

I defined the names of the tabs as numbers 1-3. This was done with the objective of dynamically taking the data for the body from the alldata matrix.

So I add this piece of code to the dashboard body:

```
dashboardBody(
#Roger Federer Tab
box( print( alldata[ input&player , 2]),
title = print( alldata[ input&player ,3]),
solidHeader = TRUE,
width = 12,
height = 300
)
```

and I keep getting an error saying…

```
ERROR: object 'input' not found
```

This is all the code

```
nametext <- list(c(“roger” , “rafa” , “marat”))
bodytext <- list(c(“roger text”, “rafa text”, “marat text”))
titletext <- list(c(“The GOAT” , “The Toro”, “My Idol”))
alldata <- data.frame( nametext , bodytext, titletext)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = “Best Players in Tennis History”,
titleWidth = 300 #because the title is too long i had to increase the width of the header
),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 300, #to match the width of the header with the sidebar
sidebarMenu(id = “player”,
menuItem(“Roger Federer”, tabName = 1, icon = icon(“user”)),
menuItem(“Rafael Nadal”, tabName = 2, icon = icon(“flash”)),
menuItem(“Marat Safin”, tabName = 3, icon = icon(“fire”))
)
),
dashboardBody(
#Roger Federer Tab
box( print(alldata[ input&player , 2]),
title = print(alldata[ input&player ,3]),
solidHeader = TRUE,
width = 12,
height = 300
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `input$player` instead of `input&player`.

Comment: What packages are you using? Is this really all of the code?